# Secure data within an object

Tags: python-3.x, object, security

I'm working on a decorator class for database connections as a sort of for fun/learning project right now, and I'm curious how people go about storing usernames, passwords, etc. securely within Python objects. If I pass in username and password as arguments like `someObject=myClass(username,password`, then these would be vulnerable because the password can be seen via `someObject.password`. I could make it have a method like `myClass.makeConnection(username, password)` so it's private to that method, but if the connection times out or otherwise needs to be refreshed, this will have to be run manually, and where my end goal is ease of use, I'd like the connection to be made in `__init__` so the user doesn't have to dig through documentation to find that they have to make the connection manually like that.

For testing, I put this data in a .yaml with `chmod 600` like it was an ssh key, and passed the path to it as a parameter so it's only read when the object makes the database connection, but is not preserved (private to that method instead of parent object), but that only works for my specific purpose right now, and I want this to work more generally like the `mysql-connector` object.

Is there a way to pass in this password, and it either make some sort of hash to store it in inside the object, or some sort of hidden variable that can't be called from outside? I'd hate to make it a method people have to call every time it needs to reestablish connection

Comment: Security is a huge topic and as such you need to dive deeper: what are you protecting against -- device filesystem compromise? Remote access? device memory compromise? python language compromise? No security is perfect (and anyone who tells you so is wrong); but you can harden your security against various threats if you can identify what the threats are you want to mitigate against. Hashing data is fine, as long as the hash is of a high enough entroy and slow enough (not MD5!) and the unhashed source is safe from the risk you're trying to counter.

Comment: My main worry here was device memory compromise, or some sort of injection attack, but you make a good point. I just don't want to leave a gaping hole in my code there if the issue I mentioned with `someObject.password` is as serious as I think it is